# Why does it work in PHP?

Tags: php, exploit

This is a PHP script.

```
<?php

eval(" echo 0?>');echo 1 ");
echo 2;

?>
```

The output is **`0');echo 1 2`**.
And it seems that **`?>`** tells `eval` to just print the rest of the string. Is it correct behaviour or can someone explain why it happens?

Comment: `?>` closes the PHP code and the rest is interpreted as HTML and just sent to the browser.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes you are right; the problem is that echo 2 is executed!

Comment: `eval` expects PHP and doesn't need the opening `<?php` but the `?>` ends the PHP.  Think of `eval` as like a virtual machine, it executes it's code independent of the PHP in the page that has the `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

The `?>` closes the PHP code only within the eval-ed code, and the rest is interpreted as HTML and just sent to the browser.  `eval()` expects PHP and doesn't need the opening `<?php`, but the `?>` ends the PHP. Think of `eval()` as a virtual machine, it executes it's code independent of the PHP in the page that has the `eval()`.  So:

```
<?php         // start executing PHP

// evaluate PHP independently, inside a function
// echo 0
eval(" echo 0 
?>            // end PHP execution
');echo 1 "   // output as HTML
 );           // end the eval() function execution
echo 2;       // since eval() is complete as a PHP function, continue PHP execution

?>            // end PHP execution
```

Comment: thanks man. "rest is interpreted as HTML" - this is what  I wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, when the webserver gets the page an sees `<?php` is sends it to PHP to parse and the eval does sorta the same.  Once `?>` is encountered PHP is done and the rest is HTML.  The same as if your page didn't have `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

The statements that are executed are:

1. `eval(" echo 0?>');echo 1 ");`
2. `echo 2;`

The first one is very similar to running this PHP code:

```
<?php

echo 0
?>

'); echo 1
```

And it clearly prints `0` followed by `'); echo 1`.

Then the second statement is executed, that prints `2`.